# Run PHP Using CMD in Windows

Tags: php

How to run php in cmd.. I tried to run it using php filename.php by giving correct for that php file.. but i got the error as,

**'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: You need to ensure the PHP directory you have PHP installed in is on your windows PATH system variable.  Or you can run php from within your PHP directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if you have path to PHP in your Environment Variables.

```
"My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path"
```

Or you could use command line for that. Make sure to set actual path.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\php
```

Comment: Try looking in D:/xampp/php

Comment: its not working :( i gave command as 'set path = d:\xampp\php' in cmd

Comment: Try this tutorial then:

http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html

And you should _change_ PATH variable. Don't delete what's in it already.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably meant for super user, but regardless I will answer it.

This is since you don't have php installed. I would suggest installing Cygwin, and installing PHP into that. More info on this [here](http://www.garethhunt.com/2008/02/06/php-and-cygwin/).

Answer (score 0):

@Sergejs Rižovs answer is already hit the spot, but it seems that your command may not actually correct. take a look at [here](http://ss64.com/nt/path.html) for more reference about set path command